# How to get predictions from mvpart package

Tags: r, package, regression

Suppose I have fit a multivariate regression tree using `mvpart`. How would I get the multivariate predictions on unseed data from the fit?

For example suppose I am working with the following fit:

```
require(mvpart)
data(spider)
fit <- mvpart(data.matrix(spider[,1:12])~data.matrix(spider[,13:ncol(spider)]),spider,xv="1se",pca=TRUE)
```

How can I get the `predict` function to work with `fit`?

For example if I wanted to predict a single row, suppose `spider[1,]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same question and think I managed to figure it out. You probably have by now as well, but for other people who found this by googling:

If you're predicting a multivariate response (which is why you're using mvpart), make sure to select type="matrix" when you run predict.rpart.

```
##setup your mvpart fitting    
require(mvpart)
data(spider)
fit <- mvpart(data.matrix(spider[,1:12])~data.matrix(spider[,13:ncol(spider)]),spider,xv="1se",pca=TRUE)

###predict from testing data,
###you don't need to seperate test.x and test.y since the predict function is only looking for the x variables in the mvpart model
fit.predict<-predict(fit, newdata=test.data, type="matrix")
```

You can select a single row from the fit.predict object:

```
fit.predict[1,]
```